# probability of getting three cards with consecutive value marked on them and they are of different suits

Tags: probability, card-games

Need to find the probability when three cards are chosen from a deck of 52 cards, the three cards have consecutive values marked on them and they are from different suit (Ace - 1, Jack - 11, Queen - 12 and king - 13)

My approach is:

Lets say that the set of numbers we got is 1,2,3 -

> probability of choosing 1 is 4/52

> probability of choosing 2 is 3/51 (ignoring the card with value 2 from the 1st suit from which 1 was picked)

> probability of choosing 3 is 2/51 (ignoring the card with value 3 from the first two suits from where card with value 1 & 2 were picked)

there are total 11 such cases -> (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5),...(11,12,13)

IMO the probability should be: 11*(4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is much more complicated than that.

For one thing, if the $3$ card hand turns out to be $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, these $3$ cards can be selected in any order.

For another, if the first card selected is (for example) a $(3)$, there are $3$ different sequences possible. Namely, $[(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)].$

Further, the Ace may count high or low.

So, although $[1,2,13=king]$ does not count, $[1,12=queen,13=king]$ does count.

---

So, the approach that I prefer is

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

where $~\displaystyle D = \binom{52}{3}$.

So, the problem has been reduced to computing $N$.

---

For any given sequence of $[n,n+1,n+2]$ there are $4$ choices for the suit of $(n)$, and then $3$ choices for the suit of $(n+1)$ and then $(2)$ choices for the suit of $(n+2)$.

Then, $(4 \times 3 \times 2) = 24$ suit choices.

Forther, the low card can range anywhere from $(1=Ace)$ through $(12=Queen)$, so you have $12$ choices for the ranks involved.

Therefore, $N = 12 \times 24 = 288.$

Final computation:

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{288}{\binom{52}{3}}.$$

**Edit**
If $(1=Ace)$ is not permitted to count high, then you have to deduct $24$ from $N$.  So the computation would be

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{264}{\binom{52}{3}}.$$

---

Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) do display your Math.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment question of the OP (i.e. original poster).

> ok, can you please mention the condition which I may have extraneously added or I have missed in my approach?

Assuming that $(1=Ace)$ only counts low, your approach has $2$ major flaws.

The 1st flaw is that if the first card involved is a $(2)$, then you have the possibility of $2$ different sequences.  Either $[1,2,3]$ or $[2,3,4].$  Similarly, if a $3$ is involved, then there are potentially $3$ different sequences:
$[(1),(2),(3)],[(2),(3),(4)]$ or $[(3),(4),(5)].$

It is true that this flaw may be bypassed by considering the events of (for example) $[(1),(2),(3)]$ and $[(2),(3),(4)]$ as disjoint events.  So, assuming that Ace only counts low, you have $(11)$ disjoint events to deal with.  So, you ask yourself, what is the probability of each of these events.

The event of $[(1),(2),(3)]$ of $3$ different suits should be computed as follows:

$$\frac{12}{52} \times \frac{6}{51} \times \frac{2}{50}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, there are $(12)$ different cards that may be chosen first.  Then, the 2nd card chosen must be one of the $8$ cards of a different rank.  Of these $8$ cards, you have to eliminate the $2$ cards of matching suits.

So, you end with a computation of

$$\frac{11 \times 12 \times 6 \times 2}{52 \times 51 \times 50}$$

This agrees with the computation that I gave of

$$\frac{264}{\binom{52}{3}}.$$

However, your approach was complicated, and left more room for error.

Comment: So what is wrong in considering possibilities like: (4/52)*(3/51)*(2/50) by ignoring the suits from which cards have been picked previously)?

Comment: @infinite Yes, it was wrong.  The whole approach of attempting to use the probability of certain events makes the problem much more complicated than it needs to be.  Further, assuming that you agree with my analysis, any such attempt that results in a different computation must be wrong.  Problems such as this one were designed to be easily attacked through Combinatorics.

Comment: ok, can you please mention the condition which I may have extraneously added or I have missed in my approach?

Comment: @infinite See the Addendum that I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my reasoning, based on a solution I came up with on my own. The answer above verified my solution, and I believe it explains it a little better.

---

In a 52-card set, we can assume the following are true:

- There are 4 suits
- There are 13 ranks in each suit (shown in order below)

Now, when Ace (A) counts as *either* a low and high card, we observe the following orderings:

- A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K   <-- Ace counts as low
- 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A   <-- Ace counts as high

From the above, we note that a Sequence can have one of 12 possible starting points (it can be anything from A to Q). For example, we can have sequences of (A, 2, 3) and (Q, K, A). So, in the case where A counts as both low/high, our starting point is set to **12**.

Once the starting point is determined, the values of the remaining cards are fixed, and each subsequent card must be one of the remaining suits, as one suit is eliminated by each card.

There are 3 cards in the sequence, the first of which can be one of 4 possible suits, the second of 3 possible suits, and the third one of 2 possible suits.

Hence, the number of suite choices (S), is given by:

4 * 3 * 2 = 4! = **24** possible suite choices

Thus, there are a total of:
12 * S = 12 * 24 = **288** possible Sequence hands

The number of different hands in Three-Card Draw is the number of 3-element subsets of a 52-element set, which is:

$\binom{52}{3}$ =  52!/3!(49!) = 52 * 51 * 50 / (3 * 2) = 132,600 / 6 = **22,100**

Thus, the probability of drawing 3 cards in a sequence and where each card is of a different suit, is 288/22,100 = 72/5525 = **1.3%**

And when Ace can only count as the low card, then the probability instead becomes, 264/22,100 = **1.2%**

Comment: The only problem that I have with your approach is that it represents a repetition of the analysis in my answer.  That is, you are expressing the probability as $$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{52}{3},$$ just as I did.  Also, you are calculating $$N = 12 \times (4 \times 3 \times 2),$$ using the exact same reasoning that I did.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - however, I did reason this out by myself (guided by our course textbook) and calculate using same logic to end up with the same result without stumbling on this page - though I might not have labeled N and D as such in my original approach. Then once I did, I found that your answer matched up w/ mine, and actually explained it sufficiently better :-)

Comment: It is a question of MathSE protocol.  You generally don't give a response that repeats analysis that has already been posted.

Comment: sorry, am a bit new here. I am unfamiliar with what MathSE protocol means. Also I just added this answer partly so that I do have it saved, in case I ever need to refer to it.

Comment: By protocol, I simply meant that without this guideline, you could (for example) have $5$ different reviewers, posting $5$ different answers, with each answer saying the same thing.  What would be the value in that?

Comment: This answer is a result of a slight modification and application on my end, from an approach listed in our course textbook. For that reason, I would argue that this is not the same answer, as it explains it somewhat differently. The end or final result might be the same, however the way that I got there is not necessarily the exact same.